# How to navigate from adapter of recyclerview in a fragment to another fragment if we used MVVM and dependency injection by HILT

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, uinavigationcontroller

Adapter File

```
   class RecyclerViewAdapter(val context: Context) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
var itemList: List<Photo>? = null
        private lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityViewModel
        fun setData(it: List<Photo>) {
            itemList = it
        }
    

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_gallery, parent, false)

        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val photo = itemList?.get(position)

        Glide.with(holder.imggallery).load(photo?.url_s).into(holder.imggallery)
        val arg = Bundle()
        arg.putString("url", photo?.url_s.toString())
        holder.imggallery.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(it)
                .navigate(R.id.action_recyclerMainFragment_to_bigPictureFragment)


        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList?.size ?: 1
    }

    fun setViewModel(viewModel: MainActivityViewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel

    }


    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val imggallery = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imgItem)
    }


}
}
```

RecyclerMain Fragment

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
class RecyclerMainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_recycler_main) {
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerViewAdapter
    lateinit var navController : NavController



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_main, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerHome)


        initViewModel()
        initRecyclerView()

        return view
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView.layoutManager =
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(context as Context)
        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
    }

    private fun initViewModel() {
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.getLiveDataObserver().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            if (it != null) {
                recyclerViewAdapter.setData(it)
                recyclerViewAdapter.setViewModel(viewModel)
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })
        viewModel.loadlistofData()
    }


}
```

Main Activity

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
        lateinit var coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout
        lateinit var toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
        lateinit var navController: NavController
    
     

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navView)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        var bundle = Bundle()
        replaceFragment(RecyclerMainFragment(),"Gallery",bundle )

        val actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this@MainActivity,
            drawerLayout,
            R.string.open_drawer,
            R.string.close_drawer
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()

    }
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer((GravityCompat.START))
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
    fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String , arg: Bundle) {
        fragment.arguments=arg
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
        supportActionBar?.title=tag
    }

    fun navController(): NavController {
    return navController
    }
}
```

I want to navigate from imggallery click in adapter class to BigsizepictureFragment().
I did tried
Navigation.findnavcontroller().navigate(idof action)
but it gives error of navcontroller is set
youtube channnels are stating to use binding, I don't know that for now.I anyone could help it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to take:

1. Define the onItemClick Function in a viewModel
2. Call this onItemClick method in the onClickListener that is defined in
   the adapter.
3. In the onItemClick method update the value of a livedata object that
   indicated the page you need to navigate to.
4. Observe the livedata object in the fragment and add the
   appropriate navigation there in the observer.

Hope this helps anyone who is still trying to solve this problem.